# Libraries "rt" and "dl" in Cygwin

Tags: haskell, cygwin, static-libraries

Perhaps this is stupid but I'm unable to find out which package I have to install in Cygwin to fix the following missing libraries:

```
config.status: creating unix.buildinfo
config.status: creating include/HsUnixConfig.h
cabal.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
* Missing header file: HsUnix.h
* Missing C libraries: rt, dl
```

Any ideas or how do you generally find out which package to install when you get feedback that file xxx is missing (I remember that in gentoo this was quite straightforward)...

Comment: Does http://www.nabble.com/building-unix-package-on-windows-td19366918.html help?

Comment: can you add more context to the problem - what did you do to get this message?

Comment: Well I tried to install package unix via cabal, I now installed allmost all of the libs cygwin has but it seems I'm missing something...

Comment: I'm also having this problem, did you have any success in solving it?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem and I just found this.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Windows#Tools_for_compilation

Answer (score 0):

On "weird" systems, librt and libdl are provided by libc directly and we can't link to them directly.

There was a recent patch to the unix library that should address this:
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8713
https://github.com/haskell/unix/pull/8

That said, this may not be sufficient to let you install `unix` on `cygwin` -- for years it was considered simply a case of "don't do that then" (i.e. if you want to run on windows, port it to use the appropriate functions from the windows libraries instead, and if you want to use both then use CPP).