# GHC can't find foreign library (libjack.lib) that works with mingw gcc (but not mingw-w64)

Tags: windows, haskell, gcc, linker-errors, jack

### Objective:

I am writing a haskell program on Windows 10 using stack and the bindings for [jack](https://jackaudio.org/faq/jack_on_windows.html) from [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jack). Jack is installed and its lib/include paths are provided to ghc. My objective is to build the program using stack.

### Problem:

When I run `stack build`, I see:

```
Building all executables for 'hsjack' once  ...
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.6.5, stage 2 booted by GHC version 8.6.2
Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign
libraries:
* Missing (or bad) C libraries: jack64, jack64 ...
While building package hsjack-0.1.0.0 using:
     C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe ... 
        --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\jvall\Tools\jackpackage\includes ...  
        --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\jvall\Tools\jackpackage\lib...
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I've left some uninteresting parts out (indicated by '...'). You can see that the path to the library and include files are included, and I am sure the libraries (libjack.lib, libjack64.lib) and header files are in these directories. I have tried specifying both `- jack` and `- jack64` under `extra-libraries:` in package.yaml to no difference. Of course, `extra-include-dirs` and `extra-lib-dirs` are specified in stack.yaml.

### Program versions and other context:

Windows 10

> jackd --version
jackdmp 1.9.11
I installed the JACK2 64-bit binaries available on the [jack website](https://jackaudio.org/downloads/).
Contents of C:/.../jackpackage/includes/jack:
jack.h, other *.h files
Contents of C:/../lib:
libjack.def, libjack.lib, libjack64.def, libjack64.lib. (Plus irrelevant libjackserver files. There are no .dlls)

> stack --version
Version 2.3.1, Git revision de2a7b694f07de7e6cf17f8c92338c16286b2878 (8103 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.33.0

> stack exec -- ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5

> stack exec -- gcc --version
realgcc.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.2.0

*when using mingw*
> gcc --version
gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0

*when using mingw-w64*
> gcc --version
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

### Possible duplicates:

There are many similar SO posts, but I found none that provided a solution for my case. The vast majority are simply missing the appropriate libraries or programs ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476063/cabal-missing-dependencies-on-foreign-libraries-when-install-glib-under-windows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809958/cabal-missing-dependency-on-foreign-c-library), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809958/cabal-missing-dependency-on-foreign-c-library), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465426/libraries-rt-and-dl-in-cygwin)). My problem seems to be caused by an incompatibility between the *.lib files and mingw-w64 and MSYS2 versions of gcc.

### Debugging attempts:

To verify that the .lib files work at all, I wrote a simple c program which uses them. The program compiles and runs correctly when using gcc provided by mingw, but it does not run when using the mingw-w64 gcc or `stack exec gcc`. Sample output using stack exec (heavily abbreviated):

`stack exec -- gcc .\test.c -o .\test -I C:\...\includes -L C:\...\lib -ljack64`

```
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32  
Thread model: posix  
gcc version 7.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)  
...  
path-to-stack//stack//x86_64-windows//ghc-8.8.3//mingw//bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/collect2.exe  ....  -LC:\\Users\\jvall\\Tools\\jackpackage\\lib ....  
path-to-stack//stack//x86_64-windows//ghc-8.6.5//mingw//bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljack64  
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

mingw-w64 and `stack exec gcc` both fail in the same way. Everything looks fine until they can't find the library. Using -m64/-m32 and -ljack/-ljack64 doesn't change anything. I know the Jack2 library is written in C++ and have read that MSVC C++ libraries are incompatible with mingw, but this doesn't explain how mingw successfully compiles when mingw-w64 does not. Is any of this relevant, or should I focus on the haskell/stack side of this problem?

Any ideas what's happening here? How can I use stack to compile a haskell program using the jack bindings? I tried to be thorough, but let me know if I am missing anything. I have minimal examples for both haskell and c programs that reproduce this but the question is already long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binutils is old. The one shipped with GHC `8.6.5` misses this fix https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22948 .Without it `-ljack64` won't find `libjack64.lib` but `-llibjack64` would.

Comment: This fixed it! Many thanks, I've been chasing this for almost a week. I'd resorted to building the library from source! You've helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This solution allows it to compile, but causes problems during runtime and doesn't address the underlying problem. See the accepted answer for the real solution.

**Update**: I found a solution! On a whim I manually created .dll files from the .def files in the jack /lib/ directory. Finally it finds the libraries and compiles without problems. This works for both mingw-w64 and even `stack build`. The command I ran is

```
dlltool -d .\libjack64.def -l .\libjack64.dll
```

Can anyone explain why mingw happily linked with libjack.lib, but mingw-w64 and gcc built with MSYS2 could not find libjack64.lib? And how does having libjack64.dll fix this?